# Filtering by Angular JS Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am another Angular JS newbie and have ran into a bit of an issue on how to resolve an Angular JS filter. Anyway here is the HTML of the IDEA of what I want to do. Basically I want to filter by a template that changes based on the the heading  witch is also unknown. (As user would have to click link to get to this page and the header would get that certain name and the list would only display results that matches. I apologize, I do not know the technical terms and I am sure there is a simple fix but I do not know which way to take this.

```
<h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{category:'{{item.name'}}'">
```

I know this is not the way to approach this but this is the concept and would appreciate the help. It is hard to search for existing answers when some of the terms are so complex.

Comment: Do you have `$scope.item` in your controller?  Is that where your header is coming from?

Comment: Yes, these are replacement names but it looks like so in my controller: `itemsControllers.controller('itemsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/itemsData.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.items = data;` and then the item in "item in items" is saying to grab each item of data in my JSON file.

Comment: Have you tried `<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{category: item.name">`

Comment: I did, which did work. I also realized my initial goals where a little far reached and there was a simpler method by re-structuring the JSON. But to answer my initial question, yes!